# How to initiate a render when Flatlist content is less to have a scroll - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to do a filtered infinite scroll, I am using a flatlist for that. The items are of variable height. If the fetched list has only one item or no item, onEndReached does not get triggered because there is no scroll. So, I cannot fetch new items. Any solution for this?

```
class Vehicle extends Component{

   loadMoreVehicles = () =>this.props.vehicleActions.fetchMoreVehicles 
  (this.state.page);

  renderItem = ({ item,index }) => {
      return  (this.filterVehicle(item))?  <VehicleList item ={item}/>:null
  }

 render(){
    <VehicleView  vehicles ={this.props.vehicles}/>
 }
 }


 const VehicleView =(props)=>(

  <FlatList data={props.vehicles}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            onEndReached={props.loadMoreVehicles}
            onEndThreshold={100}
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
            renderItem={props.renderItem}
            initialNumToRender={10}
            extra={props}
            windowSize={10} />
 )
```

this.filterVehicle(item) would return true/false on whether the item is to be shown or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you fetch more items if there is only one item? You can add a condition after you fetch your data that checks if the length < 2 and issue a new request.

Comment: I am fetching the 10 items a time and since Im filtering it, there maybe only 1-2 or none results that matches the filter criteria in 10 items. That's why I need to fetch more data. Im adding the simplified version of the code

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you provided more detail with relevant code snippets. But still from what I have understood, it seems that you want to dynamically set the scrolling behavior of `FlatList` depending upon the content size. You can use `onContentSizeChange` prop for that. A very good article is available on [medium](https://medium.com/@spencer_carli/enable-scroll-in-a-react-native-scrollview-based-on-the-content-size-87430ccf319b) on how to actually implement it.

Comment: The scrolling behavior is already handled by flatlist. I want to initiate another render when filter result is none or less than 3.